# How to sort on field which might not be set on every document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of tasks which may be marked as completed by setting the 'complete' field to 'true'. The problem is that this field might not be set on every document so when i sort on it, documents without the field are sorted before those whith complete=false (which are in turn before those with complete=true, obviously).

I want the tasks with a non-existing 'complete' field to be treated like they had complete=false when sorting. Is this possible to do in a query or do i have to make sure that all documents have the field set? What's the best way to accomplish the desired effect?

Comment: Your best option for predictable sorting is to add the `complete` field to every document with a default of `false` when the document is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create virtual/calculated columns in projections and thus sorting in MongoDB unless you use aggregation framework.

I agree with @Stennie that perhaps the best option is to always add the field with default value. However you would incur storage costs.

You can use aggregation framework, but maybe that's too far off - no DB cursor, limited result size, etc.

If you sort descending (-1) then those docs will appear last in results but looks like that's not what you want ?maybe?.

If you use sparse index or `$exists ... false` then you can remove documents with missing field from search results completely. If you want you can get them in a second query.

So basically you have these tradeoffs of speed vs storage space vs complexity.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things out! I solved it by enforcing the existence of the field by adding it on insert using hooks (through the [collection-hooks Meteorite package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/collection-hooks))